# Chrome browser is error'd out on this situation whereas FireFox wouldn't

Tags: google-chrome, knockout.js

I have been asked to look into an issue in a new module in my project which is completely written on Knockout.js. I am not the original coder so I have little information to share with you.

Here is the code which is giving me the error.

```
    self.loadSections = function (sections, submissions, isReviewer) {
        self.sections([]);
        _.each(sections, function(section) {
            var submissionsCopy = {
                sections: [],
                fields: []
            };
            var newSection;
            if (submissions) {
                var submissionsCopy = _.clone(submissions);
                self.cachedSubmissions = submissionsCopy;
            }
            // logically speaking submissionsCopy.sections[section.id] is empty for three instances as the submissions array do not have the corresponding hash values but why does the script error appears only in chrome?
            newSection = new Section(section, submissionsCopy.sections[section.id], isReviewer);
            newSection.template = self;
            newSection.fill(submissionsCopy.fields);
            self.sections.push(newSection);
        });
    };
```

Where sections data structure is array of objects. In my test case it is an array of 6 objects. Each object has many fields but most important on in this routine is the id which is a numeric.

```
0:Object
 >Fields
 >id = "1234"
 .. 
 .. 
1:Object
 >Fields
 >id = "2345"
 .. 
 .. 
2:Object
 >Fields
 >id = "3456"
 .. 
 .. 
3:Object
 >Fields
 >id = "4567"
 .. 
 .. 
4:Object
 >Fields
 >id = "5678"
 .. 
 .. 
5:Object
 >Fields
 >id = "6789"
 .. 
 ..
```

The Submissions data structure looks like this.

```
Object
> fields
> sections:object
  >1234:object
  >2345:object
  >3456:object
```

isReviewer is just a Boolean value.

Here is the HTML snippet. We use template toolkit for the HTML page creation.

```html
<main data-bind="with: template">
    <div class="col-md-12 hide" data-bind="css: {show: ko.unwrap(sections).length > 0}">
        <section class="ams-section border-divide">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <!-- ko foreach: displaySections -->
                <li data-bind="css: {'active': $parent.activeSectionId() == id}">
                    <a class="step" href="#" data-bind="click: function() { $parent.activeSectionId(id); autosize.update(jQuery('.textarea-autoheightjs')); }">
                        <span class="circle circle-md circle-solid" data-bind="text: $index()+1"></span>
                        <!-- ko if: ko.unwrap($data.template.id) == $parent.id -->
                        <span class="step-name pull-right" data-bind="text: name, attr: {title: name}"></span>
                        <!-- /ko -->

                        <!-- ko if: ko.unwrap($data.template.id) != $parent.id -->
                        <span class="step-name pull-right" data-bind='attr: {title: ko.unwrap($data.name) + " " + "[% source_template.name | escape_html %]"}'>
                            <!-- ko text: name--><!-- /ko -->&nbsp;[% source_template.name | escape_html %]
                        </span>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </ul>
```

The above code is rendering the HTML. Below I have attached the HTML code which is appearing in the FireFox browser.

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <!-- ko foreach: displaySections -->
                <li data-bind="css: {'active': $parent.activeSectionId() == id}" class="active">
                    <a data-bind="click: function() { $parent.activeSectionId(id); autosize.update(jQuery('.textarea-autoheightjs')); }" href="#" class="step">
                        <span data-bind="text: $index()+1" class="circle circle-md circle-solid">1</span>
                        <!-- ko if: ko.unwrap($data.template.id) == $parent.id -->
                        <span data-bind="text: name, attr: {title: name}" class="step-name pull-right" title="Introduction">Introduction</span>
                        <!-- /ko -->

                        <!-- ko if: ko.unwrap($data.template.id) != $parent.id --><!-- /ko -->
                    </a>
                </li>
                
                <li data-bind="css: {'active': $parent.activeSectionId() == id}">
                    <a data-bind="click: function() { $parent.activeSectionId(id); autosize.update(jQuery('.textarea-autoheightjs')); }" href="#" class="step">
                        <span data-bind="text: $index()+1" class="circle circle-md circle-solid">2</span>
                        <!-- ko if: ko.unwrap($data.template.id) == $parent.id -->
                        <span data-bind="text: name, attr: {title: name}" class="step-name pull-right" title="Program Mission, Objectives, and Learning Outcomes">Program Mission, Objectives, and Learning Outcomes</span>
                        <!-- /ko -->

                        <!-- ko if: ko.unwrap($data.template.id) != $parent.id --><!-- /ko -->
                    </a>
                </li>
                
                <li data-bind="css: {'active': $parent.activeSectionId() == id}">
                    <a data-bind="click: function() { $parent.activeSectionId(id); autosize.update(jQuery('.textarea-autoheightjs')); }" href="#" class="step">
                        <span data-bind="text: $index()+1" class="circle circle-md circle-solid">3</span>
                        <!-- ko if: ko.unwrap($data.template.id) == $parent.id -->
                        <span data-bind="text: name, attr: {title: name}" class="step-name pull-right" title="Curriculum Map">Curriculum Map</span>
                        <!-- /ko -->

                        <!-- ko if: ko.unwrap($data.template.id) != $parent.id --><!-- /ko -->
                    </a>
                </li>
                
                <li data-bind="css: {'active': $parent.activeSectionId() == id}">
                    <a data-bind="click: function() { $parent.activeSectionId(id); autosize.update(jQuery('.textarea-autoheightjs')); }" href="#" class="step">
                        <span data-bind="text: $index()+1" class="circle circle-md circle-solid">4</span>
                        <!-- ko if: ko.unwrap($data.template.id) == $parent.id -->
                        <span data-bind="text: name, attr: {title: name}" class="step-name pull-right" title="Assessment Plan">Assessment Plan</span>
                        <!-- /ko -->

                        <!-- ko if: ko.unwrap($data.template.id) != $parent.id --><!-- /ko -->
                    </a>
                </li>
                
                <li data-bind="css: {'active': $parent.activeSectionId() == id}">
                    <a data-bind="click: function() { $parent.activeSectionId(id); autosize.update(jQuery('.textarea-autoheightjs')); }" href="#" class="step">
                        <span data-bind="text: $index()+1" class="circle circle-md circle-solid">5</span>
                        <!-- ko if: ko.unwrap($data.template.id) == $parent.id -->
                        <span data-bind="text: name, attr: {title: name}" class="step-name pull-right" title="Summary of Assessment Activities">Summary of Assessment Activities</span>
                        <!-- /ko -->

                        <!-- ko if: ko.unwrap($data.template.id) != $parent.id --><!-- /ko -->
                    </a>
                </li>
                
                <li data-bind="css: {'active': $parent.activeSectionId() == id}">
                    <a data-bind="click: function() { $parent.activeSectionId(id); autosize.update(jQuery('.textarea-autoheightjs')); }" href="#" class="step">
                        <span data-bind="text: $index()+1" class="circle circle-md circle-solid">6</span>
                        <!-- ko if: ko.unwrap($data.template.id) == $parent.id -->
                        <span data-bind="text: name, attr: {title: name}" class="step-name pull-right" title="Improvements Resulting from Assessment">Improvements Resulting from Assessment</span>
                        <!-- /ko -->

                        <!-- ko if: ko.unwrap($data.template.id) != $parent.id --><!-- /ko -->
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </ul>
```

Now when I reach the page which hits this function, The page displays multiple tabs each for a ID. In FF, it works just fine, but in Chrome (Version 55.0.2883.87 m), I am able to see only the three tabs whose ids are in the submissions data structure. on the forth iteration, I am getting script error.

```js
knockout-min.js:66 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return fields }"
Message: Unable to process binding "template: function (){return { name:'field-'+ type(),data:$data,as:'field'} }"
Message: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return content }"
Message: content is not defined
    at text (eval at parseBindingsString (knockout-min.js:61), <anonymous>:3:64)
    at update (knockout-min.js:91)
    at function.a.j.q (knockout-min.js:66)
    at l (knockout-min.js:44)
    at Object.a.w.a.j (knockout-min.js:47)
    at knockout-min.js:66
    at Object.o (knockout-min.js:10)
    at g (knockout-min.js:65)
    at h (knockout-min.js:63)
    at k (knockout-min.js:63)
    at h (knockout-min.js:63)
text @ VM3767:3
update @ knockout-min.js:91
function.a.j.q @ knockout-min.js:66
l @ knockout-min.js:44
a.w.a.j @ knockout-min.js:47
(anonymous) @ knockout-min.js:66
o @ knockout-min.js:10
g @ knockout-min.js:65
h @ knockout-min.js:63
k @ knockout-min.js:63
h @ knockout-min.js:63
k @ knockout-min.js:63
h @ knockout-min.js:63
k @ knockout-min.js:63
h @ knockout-min.js:63
k @ knockout-min.js:63
h @ knockout-min.js:63
k @ knockout-min.js:63
h @ knockout-min.js:63
k @ knockout-min.js:63
h @ knockout-min.js:63
k @ knockout-min.js:63
h @ knockout-min.js:63
k @ knockout-min.js:63
h @ knockout-min.js:63
k @ knockout-min.js:63
h @ knockout-min.js:63
k @ knockout-min.js:63
h @ knockout-min.js:63
a.ub @ knockout-min.js:69
(anonymous) @ knockout-min.js:103
b @ knockout-min.js:102
d @ knockout-min.js:103
e @ knockout-min.js:104
(anonymous) @ knockout-min.js:105
l @ knockout-min.js:44
a.w.a.j @ knockout-min.js:47
a.eb @ knockout-min.js:105
update @ knockout-min.js:107
function.a.j.q @ knockout-min.js:66
l @ knockout-min.js:44
a.w.a.j @ knockout-min.js:47
(anonymous) @ knockout-min.js:66
o @ knockout-min.js:10
g @ knockout-min.js:65
h @ knockout-min.js:63
k @ knockout-min.js:63
h @ knockout-min.js:63
k @ knockout-min.js:63
h @ knockout-min.js:63
a.ub @ knockout-min.js:69
(anonymous) @ knockout-min.js:103
b @ knockout-min.js:102
d @ knockout-min.js:103
n @ knockout-min.js:105
a.a.fb @ knockout-min.js:112
u @ knockout-min.js:35
a.j.q @ knockout-min.js:106
l @ knockout-min.js:44
a.w.a.j @ knockout-min.js:47
a.Cc @ knockout-min.js:106
update @ knockout-min.js:107
update @ knockout-min.js:84
function.a.j.q @ knockout-min.js:66
l @ knockout-min.js:44
a.w.a.j @ knockout-min.js:47
(anonymous) @ knockout-min.js:66
o @ knockout-min.js:10
g @ knockout-min.js:65
h @ knockout-min.js:63
k @ knockout-min.js:63
h @ knockout-min.js:63
k @ knockout-min.js:63
h @ knockout-min.js:63
a.ub @ knockout-min.js:69
(anonymous) @ knockout-min.js:103
b @ knockout-min.js:102
d @ knockout-min.js:103
n @ knockout-min.js:105
a.a.fb @ knockout-min.js:112
u @ knockout-min.js:35
a.j.q @ knockout-min.js:106
l @ knockout-min.js:44
h @ knockout-min.js:43
notifySubscribers @ knockout-min.js:33
d.W @ knockout-min.js:36
a.ba.fn.(anonymous function) @ knockout-min.js:40
(anonymous) @ Template.js?1484122788:349
m.each.m.forEach @ underscore.min.js?1484122788:5
self.loadSections @ Template.js?1484122788:336
(anonymous) @ ProgramPlanPage.js?1484122788:83
j @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
x @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4
b @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4
```

I tried adding an if condition before the last 4 lines of the inner most code, but that would impact the functionality in FF.

Comment: Can you also add the relevant HTML with the ko bindings?

Comment: @sifriday, I have added the HTML snippet. Hope it will help. I am novice to this MVVM.

Comment: I don't think that's the right HTML? There should be something with a binding like `data-bind="text: content"` somewhere.

Comment: @sifriday, I have added the HTML source code. I believe it is the correct HTML template.

Comment: That 2nd chunk of HTML is the rendered results from the first chunk, so it doesn't give us anything new. I'm still fairly sure it is not the HTML associated with your error. None of the KO error messages match up. Can you search your code for bindings like <!--ko if: ko.unwrap(submissionStatus) !=='approved' --> (which is associated with the first error in your stack). I think something in your code is causing an error with some HTML somewhere else, possibly because of an applyBindings call made elsewhere with the same data.

Comment: @sifriday, thanks for the advice. I see that there are 5 instances where I see the binding like this in my template. I thought is is HTML comment. aren't they HTML comments? I removed them all, just to see if I get anything new. I have updated the error section with more details if it helps.

Comment: @sifriday, I think I found the loop which is causing the issue in Chrome. I am planning to create a new question as this question is not making any sense. Thanks for your guidance. it was as per your prediction. the HTML code was some where down the same template. A particular div is going blank in the chrome where as it is appearing correctly in FF.  I will still need your guidance on the new question though.

Comment: In the interests of tidying up loose ends, can I ask if you have created your new question and if so I could vote to close this question or maybe you could delete it?

Comment: @sifriday, Thanks for asking.I have created a new question and I thought you would have viewed it. Anyways, Here is the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936536/facing-knockout-js-binding-error-in-chrome-browser.  how can I delete this question?